# Objective C - Objects created in code disappear after switching view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have a simple app with two views in the storyboard, with two segues connecting them together. in the viewDidLoad of each controller I programmatically create one button, and the action for that button is to switch to the other view. The main code for one of the view controllers is shown here The code for the second one is identical except for the view controller and button names.

```
UIButton*           button;

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (!button) {
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 20);
        button.center = CGPointMake(200, 200);
        button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        [button setTitle:@"View 2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setBackgroundColor: [UIColor blueColor]];
        [button setTitleColor: [UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.tag = 7;
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(view2Action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:button];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"View 1 already created. Button Tag: %d", button.tag);
    }
}

- (void)view2Action:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue2" sender:self];
}

@end
```

The first view appears correctly creates the button and shows it. Clicking the button takes me to the second view, and the corresponding button there is also created and shown. And when I click this button, I do go back to the first view. But, the problem is now the button in the first view is not visible anymore. The code "if (!button)" recognizes the existence of the button, and prints the message "View 1 already created. Button Tag: 7". It seems that all the button properties are there except its graphic.

One point, if instead of creating button in code I place the button provided in the storyboard, this problem does not occur. What do I need to make the button stay displayed?

Any help will be appreciated.

Behzad

Comment: Did you declare your UIButton as a property or instance variable?

Comment: As an instance variable.

Comment: so you have 2 segues, "segue1" from VC1 to VC2, "segue2" from VC2 to VC 1?

Comment: Wow! Thank you GellertLee!  That was it. Changing to property fixed it. Very much appreciated. How do I give a thumbs up to your answer?

Comment: actually segue1 going to VC1...

Comment: Gallert,  it seems that I jumped the gun a bit. Please see the comments on the answer that Son of a Beach gave below.

Answer (score 1):

Your `UIButton* button;` variable declaration is in the wrong place.  It's not syntactically illegal, but it's in the global scope of the file and of anything that imports that file.  It's not technically an instance variable, as it is not within the scope of the class (neither in its `@interface` nor in its `@implementation`).  It should be declared as either an instance variable or a property.

Without seeing more of your code, I can't entirely explain the behaviour you're seeing.  As a global variable it should still remain available.  However, perhaps your two UIViewController classes are both accessing the same global variable, and overwriting the button properties, and the second one has stolen it and added it to it's view (removing it from the view of the first view controller).  You could test this by logging it's memory address and see if it is the same in both instances, or by testing its `superview` property and comparing that with the view of both your view controllers.

To declare it as an instance variable or as a property, it should be within either the `@interface / @end` section or the `@implementation / @end` section.  If declaring it as a property, then it should then be preceded by `@property (...)`.  Eg:

```
@implementation ViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *button;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...
    ...
```

Note that this is normally done in the `@interface`, but it is permissible in the `@implementation`.

(This answer is based largely on the comments from both @Gellert_Lee and yourself.)

Comment: Thank you Son of a Beach. :-) I have attached here the link for the whole example project https://www.dropbox.com/s/2pflx79rqh0gj02/Test1.zip?dl=0

Comment: I did move the declarations to the interface section and made them property (nonatomic, strong). The behavior of the program changed, but not the way I thought. Before this change the "if(!_button1)"  would result in YES on the first entry, and NO when returning from View2. But after the changes, this test always results in YES.

Comment: So, the button is created always, and that made me think that the problem is solved. The new behavior is not necessarily wrong. It seems to be behaving as I wanted. But I see one worrying issue. When I switch back and forth between the two views, the memory usage of the app creeps up. This is not by much for this example project, but for my actual project, with a lot of components, every V1>V2>V1 increases the memory usage by about 5MB. Does this seem okay to you guys?

Comment: BTW, I tried putting the @property... line in the implementation, but it failed with a message "Unexpected @ in the program"

Comment: One more result: I changed all the @property variable back to instance, and moved them into the implementation block. I still have the memory creep up, but now it is 0.5MB-1MB for each V1>V2>V1. Still the same questions. Why? And is it okay?

Comment: Okay! I finally fixed the memory creep by removing all subviews from current view before performing segue. That blanked the screen before view transition, and that was not very desirable. So in segue I started a timer set for 2s, and did the removing after the timer trip. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved after multiple tries at different things. And Thanks to help from Gellert Lee, and Son of the Beach. If you need to know how, please read through the comments in the answer above.